# Install MSI on remote host using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

Hello I can't install `file.msi` in PowerShell on the remote computer. I can copy `file.msi` to remote computer but this job isn't execute. This one-liner working only when PowerShell is running like a admin:

```
Invoke-Command -Credential(Get-Credential) -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
   Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs {msiexec.exe '/i' "C:\Users\file.msi", '/passive'}
}
```

Comment: Try to add `-Wait` to `Start-Process` as shown in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407353/issues-with-powershell-invoke-command. If won't work, there is another trick I can post

Comment: -Wait is not working

Answer (score 1):

Following approach should work to be used as scripblock, you will need to find a way for your package to perform the `$logcheck`, either event log or a file. This sample had MS Office unistall.

Note, if you are planning to run it on large number of workstations/regularly I would suggest to replace `while($true)` with finite for loop or timelapse.

I have also placed your execution script as is, but for me msiexec.exe worked without need to do PowerShell

```
$scriptUninstallApp = {
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs {msiexec.exe '/i' "C:\Users\file.msi", '/passive'}
  $logcheck = ""
  while($true)
  {   
    if($logcheck -match "Windows Installer removed the product")
    {
      return
    }
    else
    {
      start-sleep -Seconds 1
      [string]$logcheck = get-eventlog -logname application -newest 10 -Source msiinstaller | ?{$_.message -like "*Windows Installer removed the product. Product Name: Microsoft Office*"} | select -ExpandProperty message
    }
  }
}

Invoke-Command -Credential(Get-Credential) -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $scriptUninstallApp
```